# How I can compare between classifiers on data set by using any t-test?

Tags: classification, weka, document-classification, text-classification

I want to compare between classifiers on data sets by using any t-test. my question here what i should use for this comparison. ex. classifier 1 I will build column for accuracy, precision, recall ,...etc;  and the same for classifier 2. then apply any t-test. is this logical? if not how I can do this comparison? and which tool that can do this comparison?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental question is what are you trying to show?

You can try what you suggest (t-test) as long as you're sure that the distribution of the accuracy (or whatever you measure across the different datasets: recall, precision, etc) is normally distributed. In my opinion it is not clear that they would be.

To compare the performance of two classifiers over a dataset people usually compute an [ROC curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) and usually use the Equal Error Rate or the Area under the curve (AUC). The AUC is connected to the Mann-Whitney U statistic.

Other thing that is commonly done when comparing two binary classifiers over a fixed dataset is to evaluate a [McNemar test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test) to evaluate if the difference in performance is statistically significant.

Comment: thanks dear carlosdc for your answer, really i need to learn how i used McNemar test or Paired t-test to show if the difference in performance is statistically significant. can you explain how i can do this? thanks again